# Ошибка при выводе данных из sqlite на listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursoradaper

Всем привет, я делаю делаю приложение которое выводит данные из бд на listview, сделал вроде все как по [инструкции](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html) но он всеравно вылетает, подскажите в чем ошибка

Вот часть кода класса бд

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    public static final String DB_NAME = "basa.db";
    public static String DB_PATH = "";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 6;

private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

//получить все данные из таблицы
    public Cursor getAlldata(){
        return mDataBase.query(SPONSORS_TABLE_, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    }
```

И вот сам класс активити

```
public class Play extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listSposn;
    DbHelper db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        db = new DbHelper(this);
        //db.open();

        String[] from = new String[] {DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SNSR, DbHelper.COLUMN_tagline_SNSR};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvText, R.id.listSposn};

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        listSposn = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSposn);
        listSposn.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    }
}
```

Вот логи консоли

```
09-02 07:27:35.760 12712-12712/paradoks.ru.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: paradoks.ru.login, PID: 12712
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{paradoks.ru.login/paradoks.ru.login.Play}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
     at paradoks.ru.login.Play.onCreate(Play.java:29)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
09-02 07:27:37.820 12712-12712/paradoks.ru.login I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12712 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам же русским языком пишут в чем проблема:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

А так как объект у нас тут:

> (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSposn);

То надо посмотреть повнимательнее на activity_play, которого тут нет.